# Interpratation of the sts NIST test

Tags: random, numbers, generator

I generated a random sequence of bits (121000 bits) and I analyzed the sequence with the NIST test but I cannot understand the result: in several case I have a good proportion but a P-value=0.000000, like for the Rank test the proportion is 54/55 while P-value=0.000000. The same also for all the NonOverlappingTemplate and the LinearComplexity tests.

Do you have any suggestions??
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

For future readers:

It's described in the [documentation](http://csrc.nist.gov/groups/ST/toolkit/rng/documentation_software.html), section 4.2.2. Proportion 54/55 means 54 of 55 sequences have their p-values in expected interval, so all 54 individually passed. But the resulting P-value is "p-value of p-values" and if it's zero, there is something strange with those p-values when assessing them together. Maybe all of them were in the expected interval, but all of them near the top endpoint. Or there were none in the middle. Or something more subtle, but still suspicious from the statistical point of view.

My advice: 1) Try using more sequences. 55 sequences are stated *minimum* for meaningful result, so the probability of occasional bad result even with a good generator is probably still non-negligible. Also take care to not unintentionally provide the generator with duplicate sequences.

2) Use longer sequences. While 121000 is enough for Rank test, at least 10^6 is recommended for LinearComplexity test. That means (besides other things) the code is probably not tested for so short sequences and may give numerically subtly skewed results - which is then detected when computing final p-value.

Or the generator is just bad. But not enough bad to make the revelation possible just with one of the simple individual tests which would point to simple obvious cause (and that are bad news if your plan is to repair it).

Answer (score 0):

Adding to [@JJZ](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5478139/jjz)'s answer:

Read the section 2 of the [documentation](https://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/Legacy/SP/nistspecialpublication800-22r1a.pdf) and especially the "Input Size Recommendation" of each test. You will see that most of the times, you need sequences of at least 1 million bits in length. 
Also make sure you adjust some tests' parameters before running them (You have the possibility to do this, when you run the NIST's package).